# SBT: how to make subprojects depend on each other during dev, and also when published as maven artefacts?

Tags: scala, sbt

During dev I'm using the following syntax:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(runner)
```

But for publishing I need to this this:

```
libraryDependencies += ... % ... % ...
```

But I don't want the `libraryDependencies` thing to exist during dev, otherwise i'd need to publishLocal every compile which is annoying. Is there any good solution short of commenting that out and putting it back in whenever i publish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't add sub-projects as `libraryDependencies`, not even during `publish`.

Now to publish modules you can create a simple `publishSettings` variable:

```
val publishSettings : Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    publishTo := Some("your company releases" at "http://yourrepository"),
    credentials += Credentials(
      "Repository",
      "repositoryUrl",
      "username",
      "password!"
    ),
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    publishArtifact in Test := false,
    pomIncludeRepository := { _ => true }
  )

lazy val main = Project(..).aggregate(subproject1, subproject2, // etc)

lazy val subproject1 = Project(
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ publishSettings
);
lazy val subproject2 = Project(
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ publishSettings
).dependsOn(subproject1)
```

SBT will now automatically re-compile dependencies in the background. Don't add them as `libraryDependencies`, only put them in `dependsOn`.

Comment: How does that solve my problem though? If i make some other project `P` depend on this `main`, will `P` automatically pull down `subproject1` and `subproject2`? My experience trying that found that they didn't and i got `ClassNotFound`s unless I took `P` and explicitly added dependencies in `subproject1` and `subproject2` myself, which is not ideal

Comment: @LiHaoyi Why don't you try it? That's how it works, you never have to pull yourself.

Comment: I did try it, it didn't work =( unless I did something wrong. I'll try again and come up with a minimal example if it doesn't work

Comment: @LiHaoyi Are you using Eclipse for development?

Comment: All this stuff is through the SBT terminal

Comment: Looks like things magically started working when I did as you described; not sure what I did wrong, but that it works is enough for me!